# Is there a simple way to replace NAs in a factor variable with a value?

Tags: r, na

I've read some answers on this site, but they don't provide simple answers.So, How can I replace NAs in a factor variable with a value

```
a<-c(1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
lv<-c(1,3,2)
lb<-c("a","b","c")
f<-factor(a,levels=lv,labels=lb)
#I want to replace NAs with "b"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you want. If `f` is supposed to be a factor, it can not contain 5 in the sense of the number 5, because 5 is numeric, not a factor. Or do you want to have the label `"5"`, wherever there is `NA`? This can be done.

Comment: @Stibu sorry for the mistake . I want to replace NAs with "b"

Comment: Please link to the other answers you found and why they didn't solve your problem. There might even not be a "simple answer".

Comment: Anton's answer below is simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing values and levels here. In your factor variable 2 corresponds to `"b"` level.

`f[is.na(f)] <- "b"`

Without converting your factor back to vector, I don't think you can replace the original values.

Comment: Maybe you could add to your solution that this works only, because `"b"` be is already defined as a level of the factor `f`. This: `f[is.na(f)] <- "d"` won't work. Not that you did anything wrong, of course, but I think it would help to understand how doing this with a factor is different to doing the same with a character vector.